# UI Freezes using await on react native

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I have read a lot about this topic but I really don't understand what is happening in my case.

I'm using Firebase Authentication like:

```
async login () {
    try {
      const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
      const token = await user.getToken()
      goTo.Home()
    } catch (err) {
      console.trace(err)
      this.setState({error: err})
    }
  }
```

The problem here is that It never executes `goTo.Home()`, it keep loading all the time. I think the problem can be the await but I'm not really sure.

If so, can you please tell me why?

Thank you!

Comment: Why is this question tagged with "C#"? It looks like Javascript, but there's no `await` in Javascript. Puzzled.

Comment: @Krumelur `await` is an ES6 way of waiting for promises to resolve within an async marked function

Comment: Interesting. It's been a while since I used Javascript; oh, and the C# tag is gone :-)

Comment: Code looks fine. Maybe one of the async function call is not responding or loading forever. Put a console.log(user) after first call and see if you have received the user object. Try without async/await and see what happens.

Comment: @Alex `async/await` is ES7 :)

Comment: @robertklep you're right! My bad :D

Comment: what package are you using for manage views? react-native-router-flux?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? It seems like Firebase async calls are also causing me freezes in the UI.

Comment: I am also facing the similar issue with rnfirebase authn, any solution ?